# Why do custom Woocommerce endpoints require multiple permalink resets?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, permalinks

I have various custom woocommerce endpoints that are loaded for logged in users. These pages all work fine, however whenever I do a release to the live server I have to reset the permalinks again in order for the URLs to load. I dont think its an issue with my plugin, more an issue with the web.config maybe.

Here is a simpler version of how I create the end points.

```
//Function in main plugin file
function knp_load_first(){

  if (is_user_logged_in()) {
    
    //Load the woo endpoints
    new KnpvEndPoints();

  }

}
add_action('plugins_loaded', 'knp_load_first');

class KnpvEndPoints {

  public function __construct(){ 

        //Add rewrite rule
        add_action('init', array($this, 'knp_portal_rewrite'));

        //Customer End point for the content
        add_action('woocommerce_account_product-submissions_endpoint', array($this, 'knp_product_submissions_content'));

    }

    public function knp_portal_rewrite(){

        add_rewrite_endpoint('product-submissions', EP_PAGES);

    }

    public function knp_product_submissions_content(){

        //spit some content out

    }

}
```

Now this is a very simple version of what Ive got in place, i have 3 other endpoints with varying functionality which all works fine. However now and then we need to reset the permalinks otherwise we get a 404.

Comment: AFAIK WordPress caches the permalinks (and I'm assuming this includes REST routes too) which would explain why you need to to re-save permalinks for your new endpoints to become available.

Comment: Do you think that if was using a caching plugin that clearing the cache might also clear those additional permalinks?

Comment: Nope, caching plugins in general don't mess with permalinks (nor they should.)